# What permissions should I grant in fine-grained personal access token to give read-only (Clone) access

Tags: github, github-fine-grained-tokens

I want to grant **Read-Only/Clone** permission to a specific repository BUT I can't see the related permission in *fine-grained personal access token* permissions list.

I want to permit only reading or cloning repository nothing else.

Can you help me achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

In the permissions list, there is an option named **Contents**. I set **Read-Only** access to this permission, sounds resolved the issue and in the token details I see what I was looking for

[image]